# Count in Python Lambda Function

Tags: python, lambda, reduce

I am learning Lambda in Python and for learning sake, want to implement everything in Lambda - I read so many posts that it's not a good idea write cryptic lambda code. This exercise is however only to learn.

Given a list of numbers and characters, count number of digits and characters

Implement the below with lambda

```
mylist = ['abc', '123', '758', 'cde']

d =0
c =0
for l in mylist:
        if l.isdigit():
                d+=1;
        if l.isalpha():
                c+=1

print d, c
```

If you could explain the solution as well, it'll be great!

What I have tried so far, I could only get one variable out

```
mylist = "abc 123 758 cde"
print reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, map(lambda x: x.isdigit(),mylist.split(' ')))
```

Comment: Try to write it yourself. If you run into trouble, come back with a specific question / error.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please follow the help documentation for posting, especially http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve in this case.  We are not a coding or tutorial service: we expect you to make a good try at doing your own work -- and then we'll help when you run into implementation details.

Comment: This is a poor choice for a lambda. Don't use a wrench as a hammer -- use each tool for its job

Comment: Updated with what I have tried

Answer (score 2):

You could implement this as a lambda, but I really wish you wouldn't. It's ugly as sin and half as useful.

```
f = lambda lst: (sum(1 for el in lst if el.isdigit()),
                 sum(1 for el in lst if el.isalpha()))

mylst = ['abc', '123', '758', 'cde']

f(mylst)  # (2, 2)
```

Comment: at least you get an overview with a dict:
`code`  `dict(map(lambda x: (x, mylist.count(x)), set(mylist)))` 
 {'123': 2, 'cde': 1, '758': 1, 'abc': 1}

Comment: @MaxKleiner that doesn't appear to be what the question is asking. They want to count all strings that pass `s.isdigit()` and all strings that don't. This just counts unique entries. For that matter, there's a stdlib module that helps with this: `collections.Counter`. Your code simplifies to `from collections import Counter; Counter(mylist)`

Comment: Right, unique entries cause of set(mylist), did a pass with isdigit with `code`, but it doesnt count:
`>>> dict(map(lambda x: (x.isdigit(), mylist.count(x)), set(mylist)))`
{True: 1, False: 1}

Comment: @MaxKleiner because `mylist.count(x)` is counting how many `'123'`s are in `mylist`, not how many strings are actually digit strings.

Answer (score 2):

```
apart from lambda there are other thrilling functional capabilities in python

# map isalpha on mylist, count True
ct = list(map(str.isalpha, mylist)).count(True)

print(ct)

2

# map isdigit on mylist, count True
ct = list(map(str.isdigit, mylist)).count(True)

print(ct)

2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
d,c = reduce(lambda (x,y),(a,b): (x+a, y+b),
        [(e.isdigit(),e.isalpha()) for e in mylist],
        (0,0))
```

Does it look cryptic enough? Would you like to maintain a code like that?

It gets even worse in Python3

```
d, c = reduce(lambda x_y, a_b: (x_y[0]+a_b[0], x_y[1]+a_b[1]),
              [(e.isdigit(), e.isalpha()) for e in mylist],
              (0, 0))
```

Comment: This isn't valid Python3 code either, since you can't tuple unpack in lambdas, so it's not future-safe.

Comment: @AChampion do the parens actually break that? I know they're not necessary but I thought it helped readability (HA!)

Comment: can we not convert "for e in mylist" to a map step?

Comment: @GreenThumb: of course. I think it's probably something that you'll able to do.

Comment: @Karoly Horvath, I tried:

`print "Digit:", sum(map(lambda x: 1 if x.isdigit() else 0,mylist)) , "Chars", sum(map(lambda x: 1 if x.isalpha() else 0,mylist))` - **Works** but there are 2 maps and no reduce

`print reduce(lambda (a,b), (c,d): (a+c, b+d), (sum(map(lambda x: 1 if x.isdigit() else 0,mylist)), sum(map(lambda x: 1 if x.isalpha() else 0,mylist))), (0,0))` - **Error** too many values to unpack (help here please?)

Comment: @AdamSmith, yes in python3 using parens in the lambda arg list results in `SyntaxError`, parens are used for tuple unpacking which is no longer available in Python 3

Comment: @GreenThumb: One step at a time. Rewrite `[(e.isdigit(),e.isalpha()) for e in mylist]` with `map`. Once you've succeeded, *then* use that in the whole expression.

Comment: @Karoly Horvath - **Thanks** for letting me figuring it out by giving pointers! `print reduce(lambda (x,y),(a,b): (x+a, y+b), map(lambda x: (1 if x.isalpha() else 0, 1 if x.isdigit() else 0), mylist), (0,0))`